# Change naming scheme of attributes when using inheritance

Tags: python, inheritance

```
class parent:
    def __init__(self, i,j):
        self.i = i
        self.j = j

class child(parent):
    def __init__(self,m,n):
        super().__init__(m,n)
    def func(self):
        print(self.m, self.n)

child(1,2).func()
```

This code is showing an error of `AttributeError: 'child' object has no attribute 'm'`.

I guess the syntax is wrong, but is there any way that I can change the naming scheme of the child class?

Comment: I think you mean: print(self.i, self.j)

Comment: btw, Your init method in child is redundant and can be removed.

Comment: In your `child.__init__()` method you could add `self.m = self.i` and `self.n = self.j` after calling the superclass' `__init__()`. This will make them aliases for the corresponding baseclass' attributes.

Comment: @martineau probably important to note that they would not be true aliases, i.e. a change to `self.i` would not affect `self.m`

Comment: This sounds like an [X-Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Why do you want to do this? What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: @juanpa: Good point about using the term "alias"…however, I think I know how to fix that — see answer I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the affect of what you want to do by using properties. The example below uses a small utility function named `alias()` to help minimize repetitive code.

When used as shown, it "redirects" access to the class-level name it's assigned to, that of the one passed to it as an argument. This means that a `m = alias('i')` will make `m` an alias for `i`.

```
def alias(attrname):
    @property
    def prop(self):
        return getattr(self, attrname)

    @prop.setter
    def prop(self, value):
        setattr(self, attrname, value)

    return prop


class Parent:
    def __init__(self, i, j):
        self.i = i
        self.j = j

class Child(Parent):
    m = alias('i')
    n = alias('j')

    def func(self):
        print(self.m, self.n)


Child(1,2).func()  # -> 1 2
```